# img reloading and avoiding 404 1 pixel image return

Tags: javascript

I'm uploading images and the processing part takes time which I can only detect client side by it being there. So I use this script

```
function: loadImage(src, callback){
    var i = new Image(),        
    that = this;
    i.onload = function(){
        //we might get a 1 pixel image back from the webserver in case of a 404, which might also get cached
        if(i.width <= 1){
            setTimeout(function(){
                var newSrc = (src.indexOf('?') > -1? src.substring(0,src.indexOf('?')) : src) + '?rnd=' + new Date().getMilliseconds();
                i.src=null;
                i.src = newSrc;
            },5000);
            return;
        }
        callback(i);
    };
    //sometimes images are not there yet because they are being processed. So we have to rerun the function every x seconds
    i.onerror = setTimeout(function(){
        var newSrc = (src.indexOf('?') > -1? src.substring(0,src.indexOf('?')) : src) + '?rnd=' + new Date().getMilliseconds();
        i.src=null;
        i.src = newSrc;
    },5000);

    i.src = src;
}
```

So, many webservers return a 1pixel image when an image returns a 404 to prevent the ugly broken image thing and in that case I want to do another round until I get something else.

However when the onload handler is being called and I reset the src, it doesn't lead to a new image load. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Have you verified that `newSrc` is correct? And that `onerror` runs?

Comment: are you using the callback on the original function call? In that case you should use it for the error loop as well.

Comment: `new Date().getMilliseconds()` is not the best idea because it could be the same value. It is better to use `new Date().getTime()`

Comment: Are you sure you want to assign a timeout to i.onerror and not actual function?..

Comment: newSrc is correct. I tried using the callback to have the function call itself but got into some strange loops and decided to see if I can just use the change src option in some way. I just thought this would be a good way. What do you mean exactly? Could you give some code suggestions?

Comment: I realized that the timeout screws things up. Without the timeout the function works correctly

Comment: i.onerror = function(){
setTimeout(function(){....},5000);
}; 
seems to work